# How ThreadLocal variable passes copy of its object to different Threads in java?

Tags: java, thread-local

Below are the example of creating the Thread Local variable

```
private static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> formatter = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>(){
    @Override
    protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue()
    {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HHmm");
    }
};
```

And Also Second way to use Thread Local

```
public class MyThreadLocal {

    public static final ThreadLocal userThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal();

    public static void set(Context user) {
        userThreadLocal.set(user);
    }

    public static void unset() {
        userThreadLocal.remove();
    }

    public static Context get() {
        return userThreadLocal.get();
    }
}
```

Now,The below line create a thread local variable and it is static.

```
public static final ThreadLocal userThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal();
```

Static variables are initialized whenever class is loaded in JVM. That means one object is created When the class loads.

****Question:
**When different Thread calls Set or get on ThreadLocal variable how is the copy of threadlocal object is passed to the thread?**How each Thread gets its own object?**
If one object is created when class is loaded ,then how is this happening?**

Comment: Have you looked at the source code?

Comment: @DuncanJones No Duncan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually part of the implementation of Thread.

In principle, you can think of each Thread instance having a Map, where the ThreadLocal object instance (of which there is only one) is the *key* and the value associated to it is the value.

The static instance of ThreadLocal does not hold the value at all, it is just a marker for the Thread to look it up again (the Thread stores the value).

So

```
userThreadLocal.get();
```

is something like

```
currentThread.privateMapOfThreadLocalValues.get(userThreadLocal);
```

Comment: Yes ,you are right I forgot that it is implemented through map.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is clearly described in the documentation for [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

To summarize I quote

> This class provides thread-local variables. These variables differ
>   from their normal counterparts in that each thread that accesses one
>   (via its get or set method) has its own, independently initialized
>   copy of the variable. ThreadLocal instances are typically private
>   static fields in classes that wish to associate state with a thread
>   (e.g., a user ID or Transaction ID).

and

> Each thread holds an implicit reference to its copy of a thread-local
>   variable as long as the thread is alive and the ThreadLocal instance
>   is accessible; after a thread goes away, all of its copies of
>   thread-local instances are subject to garbage collection (unless other
>   references to these copies exist).

Hope this clarifies.